# How to configure Network for VPN in Lab on VMware

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtual-machine, vpn, vmware

I want to configure home lab for VPN connections.
I configure all of systems but I can't establish connection between computers.
Now I don't add any Linux routers or etc.
I have virtualized Ubuntu Server 15.10 with PPTP VPN, and Ubuntu Client 15.10, hosted on Windows 10 Pro with VMware Player. I want to connect via VPN:
1. Ubuntu Client to Ubuntu Server
2. Windows 10 Pro (HOST) to Ubuntu Server (Guest)

Structure looks like this:
[image]

Comment: This lab should be a how-to-VPN one? I don't see the point of having two VM in NAT if it is the same network (as Player can only have one NAT network) - but no reason for VPN not working. So if you could please expand the "can't establish connection" part. What part is not working?